# Софт для облачных вычислений

Tags: linux, windows, администрирование, облако

Есть ли какой софт для облачных вычислений?
Если у меня слабый ноутбук, но есть мощный сервер на linux, как я могу подключить ноутбук к серверу для облачных вычислений? Например, чтобы запустить photoshop или другой мощный софт.
С самописными программами понятно, как туда внедрить облачные вычисления, а как насчет готового софта?

Comment: вычесления это не про прикладное по типа фотошопа. Удаленный рабочий стол нужен вам

Comment: @eri а без рабочего стола есть что нибудь, какие-то хуки на процессы, чтобы переадресовать на удалённую машину?

Comment: Есть режим приложения remoteapplicationmode